# Update Account When Contact Fields Change

Tags: apex, process-builder

I have a case where I have a custom Long Text field (UserNames) on the Account record, a custom checkbox field on the Contact (PrimaryUN), and a custom text field on the Contact (UName). When the PrimaryUN is set to true on the Contact record, I would like to append the value of UName to the existing values of UserNames on the Account record.  Conversely, if PrimaryUN is unchecked, I would like to remove the value of UName from UserNames on the Account record.  Does anyone know how I can do this or have samples of something similar that accomplishes this?

Comment: How is the long text field formatted? Is it like a comma separated list of usernames of all the contacts?

Comment: Yes.  I figured something like "xxxx; yyyy; zzzz;"

Comment: Shouldn't be hard at all. Just create a little flow plugin that creates a list of usernames and splits your text field by " ; ". Just pass in the username to the flow and whether or not you're adding the username to the field or removing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with Field Update work flow or trigger.Some overall idea on both for you to implement.

For Field Update Work flow :

Create Field Update work flow - set the condition when the record is change and PrimaryUN == true, then write this formula on the field UserName with Username+Uname , but when PrimaryUN == false then you need to remove Uname from current Username as you already append it previously.Maybe you can use SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text) .Replace new text with ''.

If trigger you can set the same logic except you may want to use String.replace to remove Uname from Username.